# ASP 5, MVC 6 sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am dabbling with ASP 5/MVC 6 combination and I find that I no longer know how to do the simplest things. For example how do you send an email?

In MVC 5 world I would do something like this:

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost"))
{
    var mail = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = subject,
        From = new MailAddress(fromEmail),
        Body = message
    };

    mail.To.Add(toEmail);
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

Now this code no longer compiles as `System.Net.Mail` seems to no longer exist. After some poking around the internet it seems it's no longer include in the new core (`dnxcore50`). Which brings me to my question...

How do you send an email in the new world?

And a larger question of where do you find substitutes for all the things that are no longer include in core .Net?

Comment: Interesting. Have you taken a look at this git page? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1006

Comment: You're not restricted to targeting dnxcore50 in asp.net 5. You can still target the full .net framework (or mono). What platform are you targeting; Windows, Linux?

Comment: I think/hope that later there will be a nuget of mailkit that is compatible with dnxcore50, that is what I plan to use for sending email in my apps https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit but probably not many 3rd party things will be available until after .net core comes out of beta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Core has several missing API's at the moment. These include `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` as you have found and also `System.ServiceModel.SyndicationFeed` too which can be used to build RSS or Atom feeds. The workaround for this is to target the full .NET Framework, instead of .NET Core. You can always target .NET Core once these API's become available.

So in your project.json file you need to remove the reference to `dnxcore50` and to add `dnx451` for .NET 4.5.1 or `dnx46` for .NET 4.6 if it is not already there:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
      // ..Add other .NET Framework references.
    }
  },
  // Remove this to stop targeting .NET Core.
  // Note that you can't comment it out because project.json does not allow comments.
  "dnxcore50": {            
    "dependencies": {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's beyond missing, as it's not even on the status page even though everything is essentially "done."
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-progress/blob/master/src-diff/README.md

Answer (score 26):

My open source [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) and [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) libraries now support dnxcore50, which provide a really nice API for creating and sending email. As an added bonus, MimeKit supports DKIM signatures which is becoming more and more a must-have feature.

```
using System;

using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;

namespace TestClient {
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage ();
            message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@friends.com"));
            message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "chandler@friends.com"));
            message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

            message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") {
                Text = @"Hey Chandler,

I just wanted to let you know that Monica and I were going to go play some paintball, you in?

-- Joey"
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

                client.Send (message);
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version should I be installing? I tried to install 1.3.0-beta6 in my ASP.Net Core 1 class library but get the error "The dependency MailKit 1.3.0-beta6 does not support framework .NetPlatform, Version=v5.4"

Comment: MailKit requires .NETPlatform v5.5, it seems you are targeting v5.4.

Comment: I am as that is what the RC1 templates setup by default, which I think a lot of people will be targeting as well until RC2 comes out.

Comment: Well as stated on your githit you can't support v5.4 so off to look for something that works.

Comment: MailKit is the only mail library that supports dotnet core at all.

Comment: Where are you finding v5.5? When I search for that all I find is info about Mono as developed by Xamarin and not by Microsoft.

Comment: Edit your project.json and change "dotnet54" to "dotnet55". It has nothing to do with Xamarin or mono - it is just another subset of dotnet core APIs.

Comment: Any links to information on 5.5? I don't really like just jumping a framework version that google says does not exist.

Comment: You can think of dotnet5x as PCL profiles. 55 is the full api while the others are subsets targeting the lowest common denominator (eg WindowsPhone or Silverlight, etc)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md has more info than the other link.

Comment: Thanks for the links and info.

Comment: np, FWIW I think the reason I was unable to get MailKit to work on dotnet54 was because System.Net.Sockets wasn't available until dotnet55 (according to the last chart - note that dotnet55 is aka netstandard1.4).

Comment: @jstedfast, I have used the code above, but I am getting: `TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server` while am setting `useSsl` to `false`, should I do something different ? (mac .netcore)

Comment: Set the client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback delegate to something that will validate your server's certificate. Apparently your server is not using a certificate that is trusted by your system.

Answer (score 1):

**System.Net.Mail** has been ported to .NET Core now.  See [Issue 11792](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11792) in the **corefx** repo.  This change will be part of [.NET Standard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md).